# What causes for this movabsq $symbol@GOTOFF assembler error with gfortran? unsupported symbol modifier in relocation

Tags: macos, assembly, fortran, x86-64, gnu-assembler

*(I realize that this is not a well-documented question, but as I write below I don't know which information to share; I am willing to provide more as it appears useful)*

I am modifying a pre-existent collection of Fortran90 programs for data processing in fluid-dynamics (which was not written by me), not substantially but more on the structural side (e.g. using shared files instead of copies and making it independent of its location).

When compiling, I get the following error (compiling on MacOS 10.15.2 with mpifort->gfortran), which I can not relate to anything since I don't know Assembly language:

```
gfortran -c -mcmodel=medium -fconvert=big-endian  -ffixed-line-length-140 -fno-align-commons -fbounds-check -Wall -cpp  -O3 -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfftw3 -lm -Wl,-stack_size,0x10000000,-stack_addr,0xc0000000  calc_pressure.f90
/var/folders/l7/2v2vqp1n1xlcp_6_gg2y7k0r0000gn/T//ccz3q6Vo.s:1537:2: error: unsupported symbol modifier in relocation
        movabsq $270012416+_stermc.4115@GOTOFF, %rdx
        ^
```

I can compile in a way that I don't get this error, but it doesn't happen changing this file: I just reference different directories (i.e. different simulations).

I cannot share the whole code, both because it would be too much and because it is not open; but I am willing to provide more details, as long as I can.

### minimal reproducible example

The code below gives a similar error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_"`

```
program main
  integer i 
  double precision, dimension(10) :: myarr
  double precision :: q

  q = stuff(i)
contains
  function stuff(j) result(y)
    integer :: j
    double precision, dimension(10) :: ar
    do j=1,10
      ar(j) = 1.0d2 * j
    end do
    write(*,*) ar
  end function
end program
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Dummy question but we never know: does your folder/directory contains spaces or special characters ?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `mcmodel`, `stack_size` and `stack_addr` flags?

Comment: Is your `gfortran` using clang as the assembler for its asm (`.s`) output?  I assume so; I wonder if `-mcmodel=medium` is even supported on MacOS?  Can you create a [mcve] of source code that creates this problem?  Are you using a large compile-time-constant index into an array or something?  I wondered if MachO64 relocations might not hold an offset from a symbol that was too large, but `270012416` is less than 2^32 so probably not that.

Comment: The "modifier" it's complaining about might just be the `@GOTOFF`, which it uses instead of RIP-relative because of `-mcmodel=medium`.  But I don't have a Mac or know enough about MacOS linking details.

Comment: @ptb removing mcmodel gives me a  `ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range` error; removing stack_* doesn't affect (adding it solved problems during execution, though).

Comment: @R.N No, but you're right, better to check ;)

Comment: @PeterCordes how can I check about clang? I will try to produce a rme, not sure if I can. I am using large arrays, but if I get you right I should have no constant index used in the array.

Comment: A constant index shouldn't be a problem.  Have you tried just compiling a trivial example of using an array with `-mcmodel=medium`?  (But not so trivial it optimizes away.  e.g. a function that takes an integer arg and uses it to index a static array.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you mean something like that? https://gist.github.com/GabrieleLabanca/9c8d2c01f8a401571206ef27339576e6. If I compile with `-mcmodel=medium` I get an `ld` error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_"`

Comment: Yes, that's a good [MCVE] you could include in your question.  MacOS probably doesn't use GOT (Global Offset Table), at least not by that name.  It probably has equivalent functionality for something with a different name.  http://timetobleed.com/dynamic-linking-elf-vs-mach-o/.  `@GOTOFF` works on ELF platforms like GNU/Linux.  I'd guess that MacOS probably makes it possible to use more than 2GB of static data, but it seems `gfortran` doesn't know how to do it on MacOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterCordes: this stuff is very new to me, it is not trivial even to connect the two errors... I will include this example and read the article you linked.